# Idea of division in a general semiring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(S,+,\cdot)$ is a semiring, then if there is $x,y,a,b\in S$ such that $a\cdot x=b+a\cdot y$ then is there any $s\in S$ such that $a\cdot s=b$?

Comment: Yes.. Sorry, $a$ is arbitrary in my post but $b$ is fixed.

Comment: In $\Bbb N$, the existence of $a$ and $b$ implies that $x<y$.

Comment: Yes, but in a general semiring, there is no order property. So I think if you all could help.

Comment: Actually in $\mathbb{N}$, if $a\cdot x =m+ a\cdot y$, then $a\mid m$. I have been thinking if it can be genaralized in a general semiring, where the idea of division isn't guarunteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is an example if I understood your question correctly.
Let $S = \mathbb N \cup \{-\infty\}\setminus\{1\}$, we can define a semiring $(S, \oplus, \otimes)$ with $x\oplus y := \max\{x, y\}$ and $x \otimes y := x+y$ where $x+(-\infty) = -\infty+x = -\infty+(-\infty) = -\infty$.

The additive identity is $-\infty$ and the multiplicative identity is $0$, we also check that $S$ is indeed closed under these operations (not obvious since we excluded the number $1$).

Your identity $a \cdot x = b + a \cdot y$ becomes $a + x = \max\{b, a + y\}$  and for $a = 2, b = 3, x = y = 2$ it is satisfied. Now the set you considered, $\{s \in S : 2 + s = 3\}$, is empty as $1\notin S$.

Comment: Good elementary trick. Thank you.